# how to get nearest school and other predefined places name with distance from multiple fixed locations?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I want to get nearest Stations, Stores, Schools, Shopping Places, Leisure Centres with distance on a property listing http://goo.gl/wIFPnz. Please suggest me how to get.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) for this. By feeding in the type into the request. You can view the [supported types](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types) here

```
var request = {
location: pyrmont,
radius: '500',
types: ['subway_station', 'train_station']
};
```

Hope this helps